# Jenkins Python API returns HTML

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins

I'm trying to write a Python script to talk to my instance of Jenkins. I am using the newest version of the `jenkinsapi` module and querying Jenkins 1.509.3.

I can get a job list like follows:

```
l=j.get_jobs_list()
```

where `j` is an instance of `jenkinsapi.Jenkins` (I used the requester from `jenkinsapi.utils.requester` to skip ssl verification)

However, when I try to get more information on an individual job with

```
j.get_job(l[0])
```

it fails with this error: `Inappropriate content found at [some_address]` and what is returned is a bunch of HTML (that looks like the starting page for my instance, the one you see when you log in) instead of anything that should look like the response. Pasting `[some_address]` into the browser gives me what I expect as a response.

While I can get some information on the Jenkins instance, what I am really interested in is info on individual jobs. Any ideas how to fix it and get the job info?

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.6, python-jenkins 1.0.1 and Jenkins 2.121.1, following works nicely:

```
import pprint
import jenkins

IP = 'localhost'
USERNAME = 'my_username'
PW = 'my_password'

def get_version(server):
    user = server.get_whoami()
    version = server.get_version() 
    print('Hello %s from Jenkins %s' % (user['fullName'], version))


def get_jobs(server):
    jobs = server.get_jobs()  # List[dict]
    print("Here are top 5 jobs")
    pprint(jobs[:5])
    return jobs


def get_job(server, job_name):
    job_config = server.get_job_config(job_name)  # XML
    job_info = server.get_job_info(job_name)  # dict

    print("\n --- JOB CONFIG --- ")
    print(job_config)

    print("\n --- JOB INFO --- ")
    pprint(job_info)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _server = jenkins.Jenkins(IP, username=USERNAME, password=PW)
    get_version(_server)
    _jobs = get_jobs(_server)

    get_job(_server, _jobs[0]['name'])
```

Jenkins API I was using is documented here: https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html